# Increment numbers inside strings by an offset

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, math

I want to search a text file for strings like these.

```
[task0]
[task1]
...
[task1613]
```

and increment each by a given offset, in this case by 3640.
So, with the example I gave above, I'd get the following.

```
[task3640]
[task3641]
...
[task5253]
```

I want each of the incremented numbers in their original positions in the target file though, 
with `[task#]` wrapped around the number. Using `sed`:

```
sed "/^\[task/s/[0-9]*\]/3640+&/" ./test.file2
```

I can get something like:

```
[task3640+0]
[task3640+1]
...
[task3640+1614]
```

but that isn't very useful because I don't know how to evaluate the expressions in place and

I'm fairly sure that `sed` isn't suited for this.
I'm thinking that `awk` or `perl` would work better for this, but I'm fairly inept at both of them.

Can someone at least point me in the right direction, please? I've spent way longer than I want to admit on this already.

For a more detailed view of what I want to do see this page on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/b3pWieGT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use Perl's look behind to find a section of a string that starts with `[task` followed by numbers. If this is found it will extract the digits and add 3640 to them.

```
$ perl -p -e 's/(?<=\[task)([0-9]+)/3640+$1/e' sample.txt 
blah blah blah [task3641] blah blah
blah blah blah [task3642] blah blah
blah blah blah [task5254] blah blah
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (this will change the original file):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\[task\K([0-9]+)/3640+$1/e' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+3640/e if /^\[task.*\]/' file
```

Comment: This didn't do anything to the results.

Comment: @slm it works fine here, it just will replace all numbers irrespective of where they're found which is not a good idea.

Comment: It also anchors on the beginning of the line, so it would seem to not be the optimal solution.