# Sed incremental arithmetic

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, sed, gnu, arithmetic

I want to change a number at the end of a string by incrementing that number by one each time I run a specific `sed` line.

The string looks like this:

```
server-port=25555
```

I was thinking I could run something like this `sed` line to do it, but it doesn't work.

```
sed -i 's/port=[0-9]{5}/int(&+1)/'
```

Comment: checkout http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed

Comment: you tagged ubuntu, which may have gnu sed, in which case you can use this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231596/117549 -- otherwise, "standard" sed doesn't have math functions built-in. Most people turn to perl for this (see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116372/117549)

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest `perl` instead of `sed` for this task:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(port=)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "server-port=25555" | sed  -E 's/(.*-port=)([0-9]+)/echo "\1$((\2+1))"/e'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a multi-liner, you can work around it using sed and shell math with:

```
# or however else you're getting the server-port section
num=$(echo server-port=25555 | sed 's/server-port=//') 
v=$((v+1))
sed -i "s/server-port=25555/server-port=$v/" your-file-here
```

Note the double-quotes around the sed expression; that's so that $v can be interpreted before sed sees it. In this particular case, you could leave the sed expression unquoted, since there's nothing else in there for the shell to (mis)-interpret.